# how to update app before continuing

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm writing an noobie app that deals with advertising and time limited offers, how can I check to see if I've added a newer version to the app store and stop it working until they update? If you have any examples to help a noob that will be great.

Comment: why has this had a -1? its a genuine question,

Comment: Probably because this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you this with 100% certainty but I believe it is very unlikely that Apple will approve this. You should take a look at the review guidelines before developing to make sure what you're doing is allowed, but I really wouldn't expect Apple to approve an app that only worked if you have the newest version. Possible rejection reasons listed below.

From [The App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

- 2.9: Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected
- 2.13: Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected
- 2.22: Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the app, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected
- 11.9: Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected

Comment: the idea is to provide information to tourists and businesses come and go on it and I dont want someone to be getting either a)too much time due to it not being updated or b) not enough as people dont update it either.  What about bank apps? surely they must have a force update option incase someone cracks it?

Comment: @user1313926 They just use encryption and other data protection techniques. Think about it, have you ever used any app that just told you one day "hey you can't use me anymore unless you update"

Comment: yes.. but cant think of it at the moment <thinking hard>

Comment: @user1313926 Ha you've gotta love when that happens, and limit this to only non-jailbroken iOS apps.

Comment: @user1313926 I see you're new to Stack Overflow! If you end up feeling like my answer has helped you, be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to my post! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't query the app story (easily), but you can query your own website. Just create a static text file that contains the latest version active in the app store, then always check that file from your app when it starts up.